# Termination conditions of scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am using scipy library for an optimization problem.

My optimization code:

```
result = minimize(objective,x0,args=(a,b,c),method='nelder-mead',options={'xtol': 1e-8, 'disp': True})
```

I am using nelder-mead simplex solver as I am solving an unconstrained optimization problem. The optimizer runs and prints

```
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 19.243507
         Iterations: 71
         Function evaluations: 136
```

I have few questions regarding

1. What do iterations and function evaluation mean?
2. What is the default termination condition?
3. How to change the default termination conditions?

I couldn't find much information on the documentation. Can someone help me with understanding these.
Thanks

Comment: I guess it is all shown [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-neldermead.html#optimize-minimize-neldermead) (see the default values in the function call which you can then also happily change).

Comment: Why is there a difference between iterations and function evaluations? Is function value not calculated for every iteration. spare me if I am fundamentally wrong.